# Integrating Plaid with Salesforce

Tags: javascript, plaid

I am trying to integrate Plaid API with salesforce in a visualforce page and I have done all the procedures my only problem is that while the response is being returned there are no transactions in the response returned is there any particular parameter that I need to add for the transactions to appear in the response.

```
const request: TransactionsGetRequest = {
  client_id: client_id,
  secret: secret
  access_token: access_token
  start_date: '2018-01-01',
  end_date: '2020-02-01',
  options: {
    count: 250,
    offset: 0,
  }
```

Response Example

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "account_id": "BxBXxLj1m4HMXBm9WZZmCWVbPjX16EHwv99vp",
      "balances": {
        "available": 110,
        "current": 110,
        "iso_currency_code": "USD",
        "limit": null,
        "unofficial_currency_code": null
      },
      "mask": "0000",
      "name": "Plaid Checking",
      "official_name": "Plaid Gold Standard 0% Interest Checking",
      "subtype": "checking",
      "type": "depository"
    }
  ],
  "transactions": [],
  "item": {
    "available_products": [
      "balance",
      "credit_details",
      "identity",
      "investments"
    ],
    "billed_products": ["assets", "auth", "liabilities", "transactions"],
    "consent_expiration_time": null,
    "error": null,
    "institution_id": "ins_3",
    "item_id": "eVBnVMp7zdTJLkRNr33Rs6zr7KNJqBFL9DrE6",
    "webhook": "https://www.genericwebhookurl.com/webhook"
  },
  "total_transactions": 0,
  "request_id": "45QSn"
}
```

[This is the response containing the number of transactions still I don't get any transactions when I use API calls in salesforce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9H4u.png)

Comment: Can you provide your request and response? Have you confirmed that your linked account is an account type that supports transactions and includes transactions that meet the parameters specified in your request? Have you tried linking an account at a different bank?

Comment: I am working in a sandbox environment I have tried adding transactions through the documentation that plaid has provided for adding custom data in the sandbox https://plaid.com/docs/sandbox/user-custom/ I have tried linking it to different banks but does that matter in a sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your query. I think the issue is just that the dates you're using for your test query are too old for the Sandbox test environment -- I don't think the Sandbox loads transaction data for that far in the past. Can you try with a set of dates from this year?

Edit: Or it could be a timing issue / transactions haven't loaded yet, which seems likely given that it works in Postman for you but not in Salesforce.

Comment: I have attached an image that contains the number of transactions using postman but still, I am not getting any transactions when I use API calls on the salesforce side.

Comment: Just to double check, did you wait for the `HISTORICAL_UPDATE` webhook in Salesforce? Historical transactions may not have loaded yet when you made your call to /transactions/get. You can quickly test whether this is the issue by putting in a sleep or wait statement for about 1-2 minutes and then making the /transactions/get request (the shorter date range you use, the shorter the sleep can be). It might work in Postman because the time required to manually set up the request and click the buttons is long enough for the Transactions to have loaded in the meantime.

Comment: I tried it didn't help but I got a clue that can help us resolve this issue I have used the currents months date in the API call and it gave me 16 transactions in return and I checked them in the postman and they were correct but I still don't get why I am not getting transactions from before the current month.

Comment: If you are not getting Transactions from before the current month then the problem is that you need to wait for the HISTORICAL_UPDATE webhook. For more details, see https://plaid.com/docs/transactions/webhooks/#pulling-transactions